# Enable wysiwyg editor for custom category attribute

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I created a custom attribute for the categories. I thought I enable the WYSIWYG editor with "'wysiwyg_enabled' => true", but the WYSIWYG doesn't show up.

```
$installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'shortdescription', array(
    'type'              => 'text',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Short description',
    'input'             => 'textarea',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => '0',
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled'   => true,
    'apply_to'          => '',
    'is_configurable'   => true
));
```

Any help would be appreciated. I use magento 1.6.2.

Comment: Does the textarea show up without the wysiwyg or nothing at all show up?

Comment: The textarea shows up, just without the editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try (without all the additional options)

```
 <?php
 $this->startSetup();
 $this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_attribute', array(
     'group'         => 'General',
     'input'         => 'textarea',
     'type'          => 'text',
     'label'         => 'Custom attribute',
     'backend'       => '',
     'visible'       => true,
     'required'      => false,
     'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
     'visible_on_front' => true,
     'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
     'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
 ));

 $this->endSetup();
```

Assuming that in your setup `$this->startSetup()` is an instant of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup`

```
<global>
    <resources>
        <add_category_attribute>
            <setup>
                <module>...</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
```

You could also do

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category' ...
```

See http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a go and see if it works. It seems like I missed 'is_html_allowed_on_front'.

Comment: An additional note: if it doesn't work for you, make sure that $this` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`, not just `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`.

Comment: The key for me was removing the other options, as is explained in the answer - I tried this a few times and only once I had got rid of the other arguments did it work. I used the`<class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>` and `$this->startSetup()`,`$this->addAttribute('catalog_category',...)` etc.. method.

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the attribute from the magento admin and not by coding, following may help:

```
 Go to admin panel > catalog > manage attributes > 
select your attribute(eg. short description) > Attribute Information >
 properties > Frontend properties...
 Now select 'Yes' from the 'Enable WYSIWYG' dropdown.
```

Comment: It's category attribute, you can't edit or add category attributes with magento admin.

Comment: I would be nice if they implement that on a future release though.

Answer (score 0):

create an sql update

for `is_wysiwyg_enabled`

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'certifications', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
```

for `is_html_allowed_on_front`

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'certifications', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 1);
```